# While it is expected to have type "forall..." in Coq

Tags: coq

Basically, I want to do `pose (h st)` on this equation:

```
h : (forall st : state, (P st -> wp st) /\ sd st) ->
    forall st st' : state,
    extract d1 / st \\ st' -> P st -> Q st'
```

However, when I run the command, coq tells me:

```
The term "st" has type "state" while it is expected to have type
 "forall st : state, (P st -> wp st) /\ sd st".
```

What is the right step?

Comment: Did you mean to paste the same snippet twice?

Comment: That is better. Just to clarify, what do you expect to obtain after running this tactic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `st` is the *second* argument of `h`, while the first is expected to have that complicated type in the error. You can instead do `pose (fun H => h H st)`.